# Helper Conflict after update of module

Tags: magento-1, plugin, helper, conflict, sagepay

After recent update of a `Amasty Shipping & Payment By Customer Groups` plugin, it stopped working.

After running a conflict check in `n98-magerun`, I got a conflict like this:

[image]

Anyone could guide me how to solve this nicely? Thank you for your interest.

They both extend `Mage_Payment_Helper_Data`

Here are two files:
`Amasty`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Amasty Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2017 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
 * @package Amasty_Methods
 */


class Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data
{
    const PAYMENT = 'payment';

    public function getStoreMethods($store = null, $quote = null)
    {
        $methods = parent::getStoreMethods($store, $quote);
        if (!$quote) {
            return $methods;
        }

        if ( Mage::helper('ammethods')->isNullGroups(self::PAYMENT)) {
            $newMethods = array();
            $customer = $quote->getCustomer();
            foreach ($methods as $k => $method) {
                if (!Mage::helper('ammethods')->canUseMethod($method, self::PAYMENT, $customer)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $newMethods[$k] = $method;
            }
            $methods = $newMethods;
        }

        return $methods;
    }
}
```

`SagePay`:

```
<?php

/**
 * REWRITE Mage_Payment Helper
 *
 * @category   Ebizmarts
 * @package    Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite
 * @author     Ebizmarts <info@ebizmarts.com>
 */

class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data
{
    /**
     * Retrieve all payment methods
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPaymentMethods($store = null)
    {
        $_methods = parent::getPaymentMethods($store);

        if (isset($_methods['sagepaysuite'])) {
            unset($_methods['sagepaysuite']);
        }
        return $_methods;
    }
}
```

I want to make sure I rewrite them properly and looking for some advice.

Comment: Which error you are facing after update?

Comment: It's a conflict. Between `Amasty` and `SagePay`. They both are trying to rewrite same core block `Mage_Payment_Helper_Data`. I'm not sure in what order or how they should rewrite.

Comment: What happens if you change class `Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data` to `class Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data extends Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data` ?

Comment: Still the conflict is present and module not working.

Comment: Sorry, can you try the other way around e.g. `class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data extends Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data` (in the Ebizmarts helper) more info on ebizmarts docs; http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/sage-pay-common-problems/3rd-party-modules

Comment: Boom, that worked and everything is running as it should. I knew there was a simple solution to a problem. Thank you. Do you want to add a answer so I can accept it or answer the question myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try extending your helper class in

```
app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Helper/Payment/Data.php
```

to

```
class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data extends Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data
```

Please note; if you disable the Amasty module, it will stop the Ebizmarts module from working also with this code. You can always add a `<depends>` to the module xml if you wish.

More info on ebizmarts docs; http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/sage-pay-common-problems/3rd-party-modules

Comment: Hymmm, can you tell me how to add the <depends> so they will both work?

Comment: Sure, more info can be found @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10143/can-you-give-me-a-brief-introduction-example-for-depends-in-magento

Comment: Perfect, I really appreciate your help. I will use the above answer for now but will look deeper into adding the dependency to it later on. Once more thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked that **Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data** class is rewritten core class. So you need to follow below steps

1. Please copy method of **Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data** and put it on **Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data** this class.
2. Please keep override method **Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data** so whenever Ebizmates extension is disabled at a time your Amasty module will be working well.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is now solved easier way by `Ebizmart`s extending `Amasty` class. Thank you for your interest and I'm sure merging the code method would work too.